# Serialise objects with TS

Tags: typescript

I have an app within which I have a bunch of classes that I need to serialise so that I can send them to an other part of the app (electron app, so separated scopes).

Lets say I have this

```
class C1 {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    func1: () => void;
}

class C2 {
    prop3: string;
    child1: C1;
}
```

In this example, a serialized C1 should look like this:

```
{
    prop3: string;
    child1: {
        prop1: string;
        prop2: string;
    }
}
```

How can I use TS to share the expected interface for each of these classes without repeating the class signature ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the class type definitions in a module that gets imported as a dependency in both your front and back-end code.

Comment: The class differs between the different parts of the code, only the serialized signature is the same.
I tried having the classes implementing their common interface, but then how do I properly indicate to TS that once serialized they still implement the interface ?

Comment: After serialization, it's all just a `string`, right? The type information would be removed at that point. In the back-end, you would deserialize the string and declare that it implements the common interface.

Comment: After serialisation, I expect to get a json compliant object, respecting the class' implemented interface.

Comment: Then what do you do next with the json compliant object? Do you convert it to a string, and send it in an HTTP request? I don't think you need the type information anymore at that point.

Comment: This is an electron app, data is exchanged between the main and the GUI processes. The data sent through those apis is basically json. I want to use TS to ensure that the main code and the gui code expect the correct data interface when sending or receiving data.